Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=container
I'm currently running into an issue with my docker builds that rely on centos7
I reference the image as follows:
FROM centos:7
Error:
`Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=genclo error was
curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"`
I understand centos7 was EOL on June 30, 2024; however, I didn't think this would break builds?
Is there something I'm missing and need to change on my end? Do I need to point to a different image?

Looks like the mirrorlist.centos.org address doesn't exist anymore. The name doesn't resolve. This might help clarify why.

@HansKilian Ahh thank you for the link, that makes a lot of sense.

Same question: https://serverfault.com/questions/1161816/mirrorlist-centos-org-no-longer-resolve

You should use next commands inside your docker container
sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*



You're right in that this fixes the error, but the underlying answer is to use a supported distro, for security.  CentOS7 is dead.

Thanks! I had this issue since 1 month and half!

Works great, now I'm having trouble with: "centos-release-scl" and "devtoolset-9-toolchain". It looks like these packages use the original mirror url.

Ok, you have to run all the sed commands again after installing centos-release-scl and before installing devtoolset-9-toolchain.

Perfectly worked for CentOS-Stream-8 today (2024-12-08).

According to https://www.centos.org/download/mirrors/
Starting from CentOS Stream 9 , mirrors are listed in Mirrormanager so use this link - https://mirrormanager.fedoraproject.org/mirrors/CentOS

OP needs to decide if the design of Stream is compatible with their environment before rebuilding their container/s on centos stream.   For many, the continuous release of updated packages in Stream is not conducive to stability, whereas centos7 had more structured release cycles.
